# Can I install .NET 1x over an existing 3x/4x?

Tags: installation, frameworks

My current config is .NET framework 3x/4x.

Because of work, I need 1x installed. Is it ok to install the older 1x in this existing 3x/4x environment? System: Win7 64-bit, VS 2008, 2010, 2013 and 2015.

BTW, might need to install VS 2003 as well as 2005 and up will migrate the project.

Answer (score 0):

After study carefully, decided not to pursue in this path to avoid screwing up existing installation.